OS detects less memory than BIOS
I have OpenBSD 7.5 installed on a Beelink SER5 MAX Mini PC. The product has 16 GiB memory, and the BIOS detects Total Memory: 16384 MB (DDR4). However, OpenBSD top only reports Memory: Real: 169M/2034M act/tot Free: 11G Cache: 975M Swap: 0K/13G. I checked dmesg, and it also says
real mem = 13840232448 (13199MB)
avail mem = 13399629824 (12778MB)

You can read the full dmesg through this link. Note that I encountered the same issue with NetBSD on the same machine (dmesg link), so it's probably an OS-agnostic BIOS-related problem.
Where is the remaining 3185 MiB physical memory, and how can I recover them?

OpenBSD amd64. In particular, uname -a gives OpenBSD sentinel.lan 7.5 GENERIC.MP#82 amd64.

hm, then I'm out of ideas;

How much shared video memory do you have set up?

@ErikF I didn't explicitly set up any, but maybe the system auto-configured some. What's the command to check that on OpenBSD (and how do I disable that since I mostly use the system headlessly)?

That would be a BIOS setting: the video memory is stolen early in the boot process.
